# Building .net applications with Jenkins on Ubuntu, can't load type?

Tags: git, ubuntu, jenkins, msbuild, mono

I recently made my own ubuntu/jenkins/git/sonar buildserver, and am trying to build my .net console applications with it.

It seems to build perfectly fine, and i run it from jenkins using mono:

```
Thermostate setting through Google Calendar API
====================
ERROR: Could not load type 'Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.BearerToken+AuthorizationHeaderAccessMethod' from assembly 'Google.Apis.Auth, Version=1.9.0.26011, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

I enabled nuget, and it tells me

```
Restoring NuGet packages...
```

during build, so it seems to catch the nuget packages.

Running everything as sudo, from the terminal gets me this:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-utopic-64:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/CalendarAPI/workspace/ConsoleApplication3$ sudo mono /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/CalendarAPI/workspace/ConsoleApplication3/bin/Debug/ConsoleApplication3.exe
Thermostate setting through Google Calendar API
====================
Could not load signature of Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.BearerToken+AuthorizationHeaderAccessMethod:Intercept due to: Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies.
Could not load signature of Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.IAccessMethod:Intercept due to: Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies.
ERROR: Could not load type 'Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.BearerToken+AuthorizationHeaderAccessMethod' from assembly 'Google.Apis.Auth, Version=1.9.0.26011, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the `Google.Apis.Auth` assembly located?

Comment: it's at /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/CalendarAPI/workspace/packages/Google.Apis.Auth.1.9.0/lib/net40/Google.Apis.Auth.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this a difference between Microsoft's .NET Framework and Mono.

The Google.Apis.Auth NuGet package has a dependency on System.Net.Http.dll which is included with the Microsoft.Net.Http NuGet package. Google.Apis.Auth references an old version of System.Net.Http 1.5.0.0 which on Windows is redirected to System.Net.Http 4.0.0.0 but on Mono this redirect does not occur. Also for .NET 4.5 projects the System.Net.Http.dll is not directly referenced when you add the Microsoft.Net.Http NuGet package but it is referenced for .NET 4.0 projects.

Possible ways to fix this are:

1. Change your project to be .NET 4.0 instead of .NET 4.5 and reinstall the NuGet packages.
2. Ensure System.Net.Http.dll is always copied locally to the output directory of your application.
3. Add a binding redirect for System.Net.Http so 1.5.0.0 is mapped to 4.0.0.0

The binding redirect may be the simplest solution.